# Regex .Net search string's positions in a string

Tags: .net, regex

How to search string within a string in c#.net? For example, I need to find all occurrences (first and last symbol's positions) string "aa" in the string "aa b bb aa bbb c" (it is simplification, i.e. aa is real word such as "zebra" or "big"). I suppose what proper way is using  class regex, i.e.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\\baa\\b");
```

Then `regex.Matches(text)[0].Index` is a first string's matching. Using Length I will get last word's index and then i will extract sentence with this word from whole text.
Or I need to use Bill Smith's methods from his book "Computing patterns in strings"? Main criterions are a performance and a ease of writing programming code.

Comment: I don't really understand your question ("all occurrences" but "first and last"). Could you post an example? Like, given input "aa b bb aa bbb c" you want output: "...".

Comment: For given input "aa b bb aa bbb c" I want output: aa[0.1], aa[8,9] where [starting position, last position] is positions in string for every word.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds like you want to search for a substring eg. "zebra" not a text pattern eg. unbroken sequence of one or more "a" characters. Then `Regex` is overkill and as @VladL suggests you're better off using `String.IndexOf`.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to find the index of first occurence is to use [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) methode and [String.LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d.aspx) to find the last

Comment: In the worst case it is O(search_pattern.Length * all_text.Length), isn't it? Is regex a faster than this simple implementation?

Comment: @SergeyPetrovsky regex does parse the text as well. But I'm sure that indexOf method is faster than any regex as regex will search for all occurences, and string method only the first one

Comment: But I need to find all occurrences. So I will use IndexOf with two parameters (with starting search from previous matching position)